# Automate download and install of root certificate

Tags: c#, download, certificate, installation

Currently we manually go to a url to download a root cert. 
However there is now a need to automate it. I am looking for C# examples of how to accomplish this. I would like to give the url as a parameter, and then the program must take over and open this url in the background, download and install the requested certificate, without the user having to do anything, or know what happened. There is no prompt for a user name and password, when you do it manually, so this library should enable me to make such a call.

Please give me some advice on what to do, or some handy articles I can read to get me going?

Answer (score 1):

Here's example how to get a root certificate from Certification Authority

```
// address - CA address
public static void InstallRootCert(string address)
{
    // getting root cert            
    ICertRequest2 objRequest = new CCertRequest();
    string rootCert = objRequest.GetCACertificate(0, address, 0);
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rootCert);

    // installing
    var store = new X509Store("Root", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    var root = new X509Certificate2(buffer);
    store.Add(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the information you provide is rather general some general pointers on how you could implement this:

The download can be achieved via a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and/or [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) .

As for the installation you can do that via `X509Store` together with [`StoreName.Root`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename.aspx) - for details and sample source see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.aspx

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The url that is used, is entered into internet explorer, then a popups comes up that asks if you would like to save, download or cancel the certificate. I would like for this to be automated, the file should be saved to some local keystore, and also installed. Is this possible with the technology you proposed?

Comment: yes - Instead of entering the URL into Internet Explorer you just use the URL together with `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` class - these can save the downloaded certificate file and then you use the `X509Store` class to install it into the Root Store... just follow the links in my answer...

Comment: Thank you. I am reading through the links you provided right now.

Comment: you are welcome - please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help

Comment: Hi, I tried implementing the WebClient as it has a Download file method. When I test with the yahoo site that is set as the default in the example of msdn, then it works perfectly. However, if I change it to the url site that I would like to download a file from, it says it cannnot connect, as it "could not establish a trust relationship". My url is https://<name>. Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: it seems that the URL you are using is using a certificate which is not accepted (like expired or not from a trusted CA or...)

Comment: Sounds like a chicken and egg problem.  You may want to initially download the certificate from a site that isn't using that certificate in its chain of trust, either another website or use unsecured http.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - true... only option I can see (though absolutely not for production) is to tell .NET Framework to accept that certificate blindly (custom validator)...

Answer (score 0):

Download with whatever http request method you like. Install it like:

```
app.ClientCertificates.Add(
    new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(
        @"c:\Downloads\testcert.pfx", "password"));
```

See here for more info on managing certificates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx

Comment: I don't think he's talking about a client certificate.